# Texture Pack on Server over FTP

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, server-administration

Today I tried to "install" a texture pack on my server (verygames) to let all my users use the same texture pack.

To do this, I found a way with editing the server.properties at line "resource-pack=".

I tried a pack on mediafire and it worked.
Now I want to use something mine, my pack.

Here is what I did : copy the pack on the verygames storage through FTP, so it is accessible in `"myftp"/games/minecraft/resourcepack/mypack.zip`

In server.properties I edited the resource-pack line as the following :
`ftp ://LOGIN:PASSWORD@ftp.verygames.net/games/minecraft/resourcespacks/mypack.zip`
with the login and password that verygames provides for FTP access.

And it works.

Is that secure? Is there leaks which would allow to get the LOGIN and/or the PASSWORD? Or even to get directly to the server via FTP?

I think it's good as far as I know EVERYTHING I put on the server.
I mean I was thinking of some spy/malware or even ransomware which could be in an other pack I could find on the web...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unadvised to have your login and password in the link. As far as I know and am concerned, The link is sent to the client and then downloaded from there. Through that, someone may look in the logs/console of the client and figure out the source of the download. Most may not notice but those that monitor traffic through a personal firewall may have that flagged out as suspicious and thus revealing that link.

It is advised to upload the texturepack elsewhere such is on dropbox or some other public hosting site where the user can download without compromising your server security.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I'll try with an upload on dropbox !